# Allow a button only to be clicked once in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This question has been asked and answered several times, but I must be missing something basic.  Anytime one of the submit buttons are pressed, I want it to be disabled so no "double clicks" can occur.  (I've tried the jQuery "one" function as well).  The click, should of course submit the form.

Upon submission of the form, the controller sleeps for several seconds to emulate processing time, then this view is served again where all the buttons should be enabled again.

I'm using VS2013 and created a new MVC app by doing:

File|New Project|Asp.Net Web Application|MVC

Views\Home\Index.vbhtml

```
<script>
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
</script>

@Using (Html.BeginForm())
    @<input type="submit" name="prevStep" value="Previous" />
    @<input type="submit" name="saveStep" value="Save" />
    @<input type="submit" name="nextStep" value="Next" />
End Using
```

HomeController.Vb

```
Public Class HomeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Function Index() As ActionResult
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Return View()
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this one:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    })
</script>
```

or if you place your script **AFTER** the buttons you don't need to wrap it in a `document.ready`:

```
<script>
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
</script>
```

and if you are using jQuery 1.6+ you should use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function to disable the button:

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Well, that disables the button pressed, but the form isnt submitting

Comment: No, the form will submit. There's nothing in this code that will prevent it from submitting. If it doesn't submit in your case, this is a very strong indication that you might have some other javascript code that is hijacking the submit event of this form and canceling it.

Comment: The form is posting to a different controller, perhaps that is involved?  Let me try using the simpler version first.

Comment: Yes, that might involve your routing setup. It is unrelated to the question about disabling a submit button on the client to prevent it from clicking twice.

Comment: Still happens with "normal" routing.  I'll update my question with the code I'm using on the MVC default project

Comment: I think this deserves a different question. Routing has nothing to do with javascript and disabling a button on the client which was your original question here.

Comment: Sorry, but this question was related to an MVC implementation.  Thanks though.

Comment: Gazillion of things could be related to an MVC implementation but this doesn't mean that all of them should be asked in a single question on SO. The ASP.NET MVC topic is huge. That's why you should stick to strict topics here, otherwise it confuses the readers.

Comment: using $(this).prop('disabled', true); prevented the form from submitting for me as well.  I changed it to $(this).hide() and it submitted correctly.